# How to redirect a website page to a specific DNS

Tags: web, redirect, dns, subdomain

Maybe this is impossible but I'm atempting to redirect a website page url to a specific dns.
The idea is to create the illusion that every page is a different website even if thoses websites are just sub pages.

**exemple :**

> `example.com/mypage`

I would like to create subdomains to " Mywebsite" such as :

> `mypage.example.com`

Then I would like my previous pages to redirect to the specific subdomain name:

> `example.com/mypage` -> *redirect to* -> `mypage.example.com`

Do you think this is something doable?

Comment: Are those subdomains already set up and serving the correct content?   In other words, do you just need help implementing the redirect, or do you need to also set up the subdomains?

Comment: What web server are you using?   Are you using a programming language with dynamic pages or are you configuring everything with static content?

Comment: Well, I know how to create the subsomains, but I'm struggeling when it comes to redirect the page of my website ( www.mywebsite.com/mypage ) to the chosen subdomain (mypage.mywebsite.com). I'm using wordpress and the builder Elementor so I assume this is dynamic. I'm using OVH as web hosting server and DNS prodiver. Thx.